Equivalent Sets in SQL
I'm creating a group-based chat that requires a message to be sent only to those within the same group. Sarah, James, and Chris belong to a group but NOT Sarah, James, Chris, and Paul and NOT Sarah and James. Here is how I've modelled this so far:
This is Table A which will link the user_id to the group_id
user_id|group_id
   1   |   1
   2   |   1
   1   |   2
   2   |   2
   3   |   2

This is the Table B which is accepted as input by the stored procedure
sender_id|recipient_id|text 
    1    |     2      | Hey 
    1    |     3      | Hey 

Table B represents a single message so sender_id and text will be the same. This means that user_ids 1, 2, AND 3 are in the same group conversation but NOT 1 and 2 OR 1 and 3.
Now here's the tricky part. I don't know the group_id for the messages themselves beforehand, this is because from the two tables above it needs to be determined on the fly whether the message will be assigned to an existing group (meaning a group_id exists in table A that contains the exact user_ids in table B) or if a new group needs to be created (there is no exact match).
This is the table that contains the messages
group_id|sender_id|message_id|text
   ?    |     1   |   ...    |Hey

Any suggestions on how I can determine based on Tables A and B whether or not a new group_id needs to be created?

I'd probably solve it by building a set of users in a message by a UNION of sender + recipients and then match them against existing groups and making sure the number match exactly.
Something like:
WITH incoming AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES  (1, 2, N'Hey')
        ,   (1, 3, N'Hey')
    ) t (sender_id,recipient_id,text)
)
, incoming_group AS (

    
    SELECT  vd.sender_id, COUNT(*) OVER() AS cnt
    FROM    incoming v
    CROSS apply (
        VALUES(sender_id),(recipient_id)
        ) vd
    GROUP BY vd.sender_id
    )
, existing AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM
        (
        VALUES  (1, 1)
        ,   (2, 1)
        ,   (1, 2)
        ,   (2, 2)
        ,   (3, 2)
    ) t (user_id,group_id)
)
, existing_group as (
    SELECT  user_id, group_id
    ,   COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY group_id) AS cnt
    FROM    existing
)
SELECT  eg.group_id AS matching_group
FROM    incoming_group ig
LEFT JOIN existing_group eg
    ON  eg.user_id = ig.sender_id
    AND eg.cnt = ig.cnt
GROUP BY eg.group_id, ig.cnt
HAVING COUNT(*) = ig.cnt


Build incoming_group which counts how many users are in the incoming message, this is a combination of sender and all recipients
Build existing_group which is similar to above and contains count of users per existing group
Join between then and make sure the counts matches as well as users.

If join succeed you will get the existing group id, otherwise you will get 0 rows and can create a new group etc.
